# ModX: Execute a php code when any Resource is created

Tags: modx-revolution

I am working on a website created in ModX. I need to know the way I could execute a php code when any resource is created and also edit template variable associated to the created resource.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [plugin](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Plugins), set to run on the [OnDocFormSave](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/OnDocFormSave) event. This event has a **mode** property which will be set to *new* when the document being saved has just been created - you can do a simple check for this to prevent the plugin being run every time a document is saved.

To set a TV value for the current resource, do this:

```
// get the required TV object by name (or id)
$tv = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar',array('name'=>'tvName'));

// set the new value and save it
$tv->setValue($modx->resource->get('id'), $newValue);
$tv->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by okyanet is correct, but I've added details for those unfamiliar with MODX.

Create a plugin, and configure it to execute on the two system events 'onBeforeDocFormSave' and 'onDocFormSave'. The two events are fired just before and just after a resource is saved. When a resource is saved, the *$mode* variable is available to your plugin, and if it is a new resource it's value is *modSystemEvent::MODE_NEW* and if an update its value is *modSystemEvent:MODE_UPD*

I've written a gist that includes the full code with examples:

https://gist.github.com/2768300

This example shows you how to target either event through a switch statement, and how to further target the 'new' or 'update' status of the action. For intercepting and changing resource fields, its quite easy using the *onBeforeDocFormSave* event as you can simply change any resource fieldname with *$resource->set('yourFieldname')*. There is no *$resource->save()* required as this happens automatically after this event.

It's apparently much more difficult to save a tv using the onBeforeDocFormSave event, because of the way tvs are processed, so therefore the example shows how to update a tv using the system event 'onDocFormSave'. Again there is no *$resource->save()* required as tvs are saved immediately when you call 'setValue' on them.

A plugin could be made to function requiring only one of the system events, but as there are advantages to using both states as shown above, and to help explain, I have used both.